# Sending Emails Using Github Actions

Tags: devops, action, github-actions

I have created a pipeline and there is a requirement to send an automated email regarding the outcome of the process to specific user. Is there a verified action to send emails using github action. I have seen couple of actions already in the marketplace but unfortunately those are not verified.

Comment: Would it be an option to use [git send-email](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email) command directly on the workflow? It's not an action, but an official git command.

Comment: @GuiFalourd The intention of git send-email is something completely different. As the description says: "Send a collection of patches as emails".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment of answering unfortunately there isn't any verified GitHub Action regarding email sending.
I can recommend you the [Send email](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/send-email) action with which I had no bad experience.

Comment: This action doesn't seem to be supported any more.

Comment: Why? Because of google dropped SMTP support or something else?

Comment: No, I am saying the developers don't respond to any issues posted on the GitHub page, not for months.

Comment: I took a look at the Github issues, and I think if the issues are well-written they receive responses from the developers. Those that don't receive responses are mostly lacking detail or otherwise not really actionable.